# How permanently align div of a stacked element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to move all div inside of container up to a div above it[image]

```
      <div class="gb-box-holder">
        <!-- GUIDE BOX -->
        <div class="gb-box gb-box-1">
          <div class="gb-header">
            <span class="gb-decor-top"></span>
            <div class="gb-logo">
              <img class="gb-img" src="http://www.scim.si/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/apply.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="gb-logo-cover"></div>
            </div>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
            <!-- <span class="gb-decor-top"></span> -->
          </div>
          <div class="gb-container">
            <span class="gb-decor-container"></span>
            <p>
              Lorem 
            </p>
            <a class="gb-btn-guide" href="#"> Reed more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- GUIDE BOX -->
      </div>
```

BOXES SECTION END -->

```
#gd-section .gb-box-holder {
  display:                 flex;
  display:                 -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap:               wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap:       wrap;
  justify-content:         top;
  -webkit-justify-content: top;
}
#gd-section .gb-box-holder .gb-box {
  display: block;
  width: 246px;
  background-color: #303030;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

.gb-box class of each div

ps. Sorry for my spalling, English not my mother language

Comment: Include your HTML. Also, I believe you may want to change your buttons to *Read more*, not "Reed more".

Comment: I see you've included the HTML, which is a start, though it is not of much help. Even if I remove the parent `#gd-section` from the CSS, the HTML and CSS do not work. Try using the Stack Snippet option (icon looks like `[<>]`) to create a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways You can approach this. The wrap that flex creates is only horizontal and not vertical - therefore, you won't be able to stack an item upwards. So it must be done in a column-wise manner. You just have to invert things in order for it to work like You want it to.

**[Here is a way to do this using Flex.](http://thenewcode.com/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox)**

Another way of doing this is using **[HTML Columns](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/)** which is your quickest option here but it will not be responsive in all browsers, therefore you will need to use prefixes and manual adjustments.

```
div {
  -webkit-columns: 100px 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-columns: 100px 3; /* Firefox */
  columns: 100px 3;
}
```

You can find a good tutorial on this **[here.](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/)**

The other more fool-proof way is to use a plugin called **[CSS Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)** which uses JavaSript to align your items in a certain way. The only con here is that it will add a bit of js bulk to your code and it will be a bit time consuming. But it will be responsive and perfectly aligned.

If you decide to go along the CSS column path, **[this CodePen](http://codepen.io/TimLamber/pen/Lrtes)** will do you good as well.

Comment: +1 I've always resorted to HTML Columns when dealing with problems such as this. May not be the perfect solution but it works!

Comment: Truth be told. But after one sees the power of Flex, there is no going back :D

Answer (score 1):

You can not achieve this with flexbox but you might want to try using css columns although they are meant to be used for text.

```
.gb-box-holder {
    columns: 200px 3;
}
```

http://codepen.io/ingvi/pen/EgAZwz/